# fillna in clustered data in large pandas dataframes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Considering the following dataframe:

```
     index      group     signal
       1          1         1
       2          1        NAN
       3          1        NAN
       4          1        -1
       5          1        NAN
       6          2        NAN
       7          2        -1
       8          2        NAN
       9          3        NAN
       10         3        NAN
       11         3        NAN
       12         4        1
       13         4        NAN
       14         4        NAN
```

I want to modify the signals by ffill NANs in each group so that I can have the following dataframe:

```
     index      group     signal
       1          1         1
       2          1         1
       3          1         1
       4          1        -1
       5          1        -1
       6          2        NAN
       7          2        -1
       8          2        -1
       9          3        NAN
       10         3        NAN
       11         3        NAN
       12         4        1
       13         4        1
       14         4        1
```

The dataframe is big (around 800,000 rows with about 16,000 different groups) and currently I put it into a groupby object and try to modify each group there, which is very slow. Then I tried to convert it into a pivot_table and ffill() there, but the dataframe is simple too large and the program gives errors. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming that what you tried which was too slow was `df['signal'] = df.groupby('group')['signal'].fillna(method='ffill')`?

Comment: @EdChum: it worked! thank you! I did try using a for loop and access each dataframe in the groupby object and fillna() there, that takes forever. Have been using pandas for a while now, still don't really know how to use groupby unless some very basic cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try out this

```
data_group = data.groupby('group').apply(lambda v: v.fillna(method='ffill'))
```

I think in your data `NAN` is a string. Its not a empty element. Empty data will appear as `NaN`. If it is a string, do a replacement of `NAN`. Like

```
data_group = data.groupby('group').apply(lambda v: v.replace('NAN', float('nan')).fillna(method='ffill'))
```

Or a better version as Jeff suggested

```
data['signal'] = data['signal'].replace('NAN', float('nan'))
data = data.groupby('group').ffill()
```

Comment: this is not idomatic, try: data.replace('NAN',np.nan).groupby('group').ffill()

Comment: I thought i can avoid importing a additional library.